# Inherit from ASP.NET ListView, "is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, user-controls

I'm attempting to create a custom control that inherits from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView`.  Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;

namespace MyCompany.MyProject
{        //I've tried this without the "<T>" as well.  Either seems to compile
         //but neither works at runtime.
    public partial class MyListView<T> : ListView
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyListView.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyCompany.MyProject.MyListView" %>
```

It all compiles, but when I try to load the page I get the following error:

"'MyCompany.MyProject.MyListView' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessError(String message) 
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly) 
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData) "

I have searched for quite some time trying to determine what is going wrong or for some kind of elegant work-around, but my searches have yielded nothing useful thus far.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me.

-A

Comment: As scottm begins to explain in his answer, I'm going about this in the wrong way.  I don't need a custom control for the functionality I desire (since I don't need to change any of the markup).  I just need to implement a class which inherits `ListView` without a markup page.  Then on the page on which I want to use it, I just need to register the assembly and namespace where I defined MyListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your markup defines a `Control` and a `ListView` is a `WebControl`.

Comment: Thank you for better defining my problem.  Could you help with the solution? -A

Answer (score 1):

As the error says , You have to inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' to create a custom user control. For extending a server control you have to create custom web server control not custom user control . The following link explain how to do this:
[Walkthrough: Creating a Web Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I cannot inherit from both `ListView` and `UserControl`.  This does not help me.  I need all the functionality which exists in ListView with some functionality I am adding myself.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the markup. Add your inherited control as a simple class. If you reference the assembly properly, you can use your custom listview in other aspx pages without problems. Below is what I did with similar legacy code:

- Add a plain MyListView.cs class to your project.
- Copy all the code from your "codebehind" file to this new file.
- Delete the original **ascx**, **ascx.cs** and **ascx.designer.cs** files.

In your aspx pages, reference the assembly like this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyCompany.MyProject" Namespace="MyCompany.MyProject" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

And use your control in the markup like this:

```
<cc1:MyListView ID="MyListView1" runat="server" />
```